# Notation convolution multiple independent variables

Tags: convolution, density-function

Is there any standard notation for the product of multiple variables? For the sum of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, we can write:
$$
f_{X+Y}(x) =(f_X∗f_Y)(x),
$$

but I can't seem to find any standard notation for representing the sum of three or more variables.

Would the following notation be acceptable?

$$
f_{X+Y+Z+K+L}(x) =(f_X∗f_Y∗f_Z∗f_K∗f_L)(x)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the equation you wrote is not a definition, but a theorem about densities of the sum of independent random variables. So, $f_{X+Y+Z+K+L}$ already has a meaning: it is the density of the random variable $X+Y+Z+K+L$. Also $f_X*f_Y*f_Z*f_K*f_L$ already has a meaning: it is the convolution among the functions $f_X, f_Y, f_Z, f_K, f_L$. Then, you may ask yourself if the two sides are equal. They could very well differ from each other, but, if $X,Y,Z,K,L$ are indipendent random variables, the two sides are equal.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Bob . Indeed it is under the assumptions that they must be independent, otherwise these equations are not valid. My question was more about the notation and whether the second equation is written mathetically correctly. Thanks.